# CSS JS not updating in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress and working on a child theme. I added a custom.css file in an assets folder in the child theme. And a folder js in assets folder and added a script file custom_script.js. First time for testing i added an alert and some body  style in css. Worked well but after some time later, i removed all content from these files, but not updating, also new content not adding. Please check what is the isses. Thanks in advance. website is https://mealsgroupuk.com/

Here is the child theme function.php

```
<?php
// // Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exi
 // BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
 // AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'iconmoon','bootstrap','bootstrap-theme','chosen','swiper' ) );
}
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 1 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION



/* Enqueues the external CSS file */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_external_styles' );
function custom_external_styles() {

wp_register_style( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/custom.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css' );

}

/* Enqueues the external js file */
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom_script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

child-theme> assets > custom.css

child-theme> assets > js > custom_script.js

Now both these files are blank, but showing old content.

Comment: Please checkout codex for enqueue style sheet and js in child theme, you have argument issue

Comment: Thanks Shakeel, Ahmad for reply. Can you help me with "checkout codex for enqueue style sheet and js". I have no idea about coding.

Comment: please checkout this it will help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177157/i-want-to-enqueue-a-js-file-to-my-child-theme

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306604/adding-javascript-to-child-theme

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: This sounds like a cache issue. Try hard refreshing your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Might be cache issue of version (enqueue).
You can change version or simply use time() to get latest version every time.

```
wp_enqueue_script(
   'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom_script.js',
    array('jquery'),
    time()
);
```

Do not forgot to replace time() (with theme or plugin version) in production to get browser and server cache benefit.

Comment: Warning! That it's not a good practice to use time() for script version, because you lost browser caching feature. A better solution can be using filemtime to get latest modification time of given file

Comment: @ZecKa It is for development purpose only. You should know that.

Comment: BTW For development you can also disable cache on your browser ! I think it's good if you edit your answer to mention that is for development purpose only.